# How to extract the number from SQL query

Tags: python, postgresql

- I am using POSTGRES as a database. I am retrieving phone from the database. It is being retrieved as `('1234567890',)`.
- I just want the `1234567890`. I am using python language. I know it is basic but I am unable to do so.
- Similar for the email id it is being retrieved as `('abc@gmail.com',)`. How to extract the `abc@gmail.com`. Because I need the values for further operation.

Comment: The quotes are not part of the value.  It is shown to signify that this is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the first element of a tuple. To access it, just use the index `[0]`. So if the variable you are retrieving the data is `phone_nr`, just use `phone_nr[0]`.